# How to implement versatile class

Tags: java, oop

so if I have 4 classes which are all derived of the abstract superclass Athlete, and each has a method race().

classes are Runner, Swimmer, Hurdler and TriAthlete.

Also have an abstract 'Race' class that extends to Race, HurdleRace, and SwimRace.

Now, I want Runner and Swimmer and Hurdler to all have a race() method  that returns a random number depending on what the sport is...so 10-20s for running, 20-30s for hurdling, and 30-40s for swimming.

Now triathletes can compete in any of the three types of races, but i obviously want their randomly returned value to be dependent on the type of race. What's the best way to implement this?

I thought using interfaces would help but I cant see how it would?

I could attach code but I realised id just be attaching a lot and the problem is really conceptual -its more about my understanding of object oriented programming.

Thanks!!

Comment: When I try to answer your question I find myself reverse-engineering the original problem. What do you really want to do? E.g. having a set of athletes and a list of races 1) for each race, find a list of athletes who can participate; 2) make the athletes "race" and produce their race times which depend on each athlete's personal skills; 3) find out and present individual race winners; 4) find out and present a winner among triatletes. Is this close to what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Option 1**

You can try to model the 'real' objects into Java classes.
A real athlete usually participate in a race -> Athlete class should hold the information related to the athlete (for example his speed in a good day) and should know to participate in races (have a method that allows that).
A race have certain properties (length for example; time to complete should vary with this property) -> Race class should hold the information related to the race.

```
abstract class Athlete {
    public abstract int participate(Race raceToParticipateInto);
}
```

However, as you specified, you want to have multiple types of races and athletes, therefore by using the signature above you would write a very bad API. You should concentrate on writing APIs that are not allowing its clients to make mistakes. You don't want to let other programmers that are using your classes to make something like:

```
Runner runner = new Runner();
SwimRace swimmingRace = new SwimRace();
runner.participate(swimmingRace); -> this should be a compilation error.
```

In order to fix this issue you could use generics.

```
abstract class Athlete<T extends Race> {
    public abstract int participate(T race);
}
```

When you extend the class you specify the exact type of race an athlete can participate into (therefore the method signature will prevent mistakes at compile time):

```
class Runner extends Athlete<RunningRace> {
    public abstract int participate(RunningRace race);  
}
```

You can define the TriAthlete class as an Athlete subtype that accepts any type of race:

```
class TriAthlete extends Athlete<Race> {
    public abstract int participate(Race race); 
}
```

But again you will encounter the same problem as above (what if you want an Athlete subtype that knows how to participate in 2 types of races, how will your API prevent other programmers from doing mistakes?).

**2. Option 2**

Another approach I see would be to write multiple interfaces for athletes:

```
public interface Athlete {}
public interface RunnerAthlete extends Athlete {
 int participate(RunningRace race);
}
public interface SwimmerAthlete extends Athlete {
 int participate(SwimmingRace race);
}
```

and have implementations for them like:

```
public class RunnerAthleteImpl implements RunnerAthlete {
    int participate(RunningRace race) {}
}

public class TriAthleteImpl implements RunnerAthlete, SwimmerAthlete, HurdlerAthlete {
    int participate(RunningRace race) {}
    int participate(SwimmingRace race) {}
    int participate(HurdleRace race) {}
}
```

You deviate a bit from the initial approach. This solution have advantages and disadvantages: you write more code but the interfaces are simple. Also by having too many classes/interfaces you might risk to make your 'library' harder to learn for new programmers.

**3. Option 3.**

In an enterprise application is considered a bad practice to add logic in model classes (arguable - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model). Model classes (Athlete, Race) should only contain the information needed to describe the entities (for example you need to know the length of the race and the speed of an athlete in order to return a plausible result) and getters/setters for this fields.
Therefore a method like 'int participate(Race r)' is coupling the 2 classes (Athlete not only knows about the Race class but also have logic implemented in it - generating a random result).

You could have simple model classes with only getters and setters which are extending interfaces in a similar manner as in Option 2 and have a 'service' class that holds the logic of organizing races:

```
class CompetitionOrganizerService<A extend Athlete, R extends Race> {
    public List<Result> organize(List<A> participants, R competition);
}
```

where Result can be a class containing a pairing between an Athlete and a int value representing the result for that athlete.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're also using a specific class for a race, it seems like it'd be best to give each subclass of `Athlete` its own `Race` object as an instance variable -- so a `Race` for `Runner`, a `SwimRace` for `Swimmer`, and so on, with all three races for `TriAthlete`. Then have each `Race` subclass have a method to generate the time of the race. Then each `Athlete` subclass can ask its own `Race` object for the time, and `TriAthlete` can ask each of its three objects for their times.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
abstract class Race {
    int minScore, maxScore;
    // set those values in the constructor
    // add getter methods (int getMinScore, int getMaxScore)
}

class SwimRace {
    SwimRace() {
        super(30, 40);
    }
}

class Athlete {
    int race(Race race) {
        // maybe first validate that this athlete can compete in this type of race?
        int min = race.getMinScore(), max = race.getMaxScore();
        return min + (int)(Math.random() * (max-min));
    }
}
```